# I am trying to redirect and test that redirect in functions in flask and pytest. Any idea how to get the code working?

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am trying to redirect and test that redirect in functions in flask and pytest. I have 2 functions. `redirect_function` which I plan on testing and `redirect_function2` which represent a longer function.  I shortened `redirect_function2`  just for temporarily making it easier to test but the output will be the same in the longer function.

When I run the code below I am getting an error.

```
def redirect_function(): 
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

def redirect_function2(): 
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

def test_login_functions():  
    assert redirect_function() == redirect_function2()
```

```
E           RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.
```

The error is a little longer but this is the gist.

Then I add

```
from flask import redirect, url_for

def redirect_function(): 
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

def redirect_function2(): 
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

def test_login_functions():  
    #with test_app.test_request_context(): 
    
    with test_app.test_request_context():
            assert redirect_function() == redirect_function2()
```

Here is the error when I add  `with test_app.test_request_context():` in the example above.
 `with test_app.test_request_context():` , is used for pytest instead of `with test_app.request_context()`. `test_app` is sometimes represented as just `app` sometimes.

```
def test_login_functions():
    with test_app.test_request_context():
        assert redirect_function() == redirect_function2()
```

```
E               assert <Response 218 bytes [302 FOUND]> == <Response 218 bytes [302 FOUND]>
E                +  where <Response 218 bytes [302 FOUND]> = redirect_function()
E                +  and   <Response 218 bytes [302 FOUND]> = redirect_function2()

app\tests\login_tests\test_login_functions.py:27: AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by going

```
def redirect_function(): 
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login')

def redirect_function2(): 
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login')


import sys
from wsgi import app

def test_functions():
    with app.test_request_context():
       testing_redirect1 = sys.stdout.write(str(redirect_function()))
       testing_redirect2= sys.stdout.write(str(redirect_function()))

assert resting_redirect1 == testing_redirect2
```

The output will be 32 for `resting_redirect1` or `resting_redirect2` in my example so if you also use a string with 32 characters you can get the same output when redirecting. Also I tested other redirects and I still get the value 32 when redirecting but I only tested redirects in the auth folder so who knows.

This useful when you have function that redirect and want to pytest the output.

Hopefully this helps someone someday because this took a while to figure out.

Also normal print function will not work it will just return None.

If anyone can improve this please go ahead.